# Possible to add type attributes when using FreeForm Composer

Tags: solspace-freeform, solspace

Is it possible to add type attributes to inputs when using the FreeForm Composer Templates? If I hard-code a form I can add type="email" or type="tel" but cant see any way to do this when using Composer.

Additionally if I add attr:required="required" to {freeform:field:{composer:field_name} the output is required="required" which although correct for xhtml, is not correct for HTML5 - should simply be 'required'. Is there a way to alter this?

Answer (score 2):

It's also possible to use an add-on like [CE String](http://docs.causingeffect.com/expressionengine/ce-string/index.html) to circumvent this:

```
{exp:ce_str:ing replace='required="required"|required'}
{exp:freeform:form}
{freeform:field:myfield
 attr:required="required"
}
{/exp:freeform:form}
{/exp:ce_str:ing}
```

will output

```
<input type="text" name="myfield" value="" id="freeform_myfield" required>
```

Answer (score 1):

You would have to first create a custom Composer Template (can be done from the CP or using the `{exp:freeform:composer}` tag as a tag pair with Composer Template code inside), and manually create/hand-code your field output when your custom field is called. For example, based on the default Composer Template code, there is this conditional:

```
...
{if:else}
    <p>{composer:field_output}</p>
{/if}
```

Which you could change to

```
...
{if:else}
    {if composer:field_name == "my_email_field"}
        <input type="email" name="my_email_field" placeholder="Enter email" />
    {if:else} 
        <p>{composer:field_output}</p>
    {/if}
{/if}
```

The other alternative is to use javascript to change the `type=""` when the form is loaded from your template. Again, you would need to target the fields that you want to change.

Finally, you could file a Feature Request, for some setting in the CP for example, under the specific add-on category here: http://support.solspace.com/support/discussions. It'll also give other users the option to vote up the feature request, and help us prioritize features to add in upcoming versions of this add-on.

As for your sub-question, there's not much that can be done with `required="required"`, short of using javascript to format it the way you want. The other option could be to file a Feature Request for this as well.

Comment: Thanks for the answer although would I be right in thinking this is only going to work as long as the user creates fields using the same field name?

I've added a feature request as suggested.

Comment: Yes, the field name would need to match. You could use a conditional for the field_type_ instead, but that wouldn't be very specific when using generic fields such as an input field.

Comment: Forgot to mention one more alternative: create a custom fieldtype for Freeform. Maybe overkill in some cases such as this, but still an option. Dev docs can be found here: http://www.solspace.com/docs/freeform/fieldtype_development/

Answer (score 1):

A similar approach if using EE3, you can use [Streeng](https://github.com/caddis/streeng) and wrap this around form code:

```
{exp:streeng find='required="required"' replace="required"}
    {exp:freeform:form
        attr:required="required"
    }
        ...
    {/exp:freeform:form}
{/exp:streeng}
```