# Possible to access fields in Composer to customize?

Tags: solspace-freeform

We have a form built using Composer. One of the fields is a phone number. Is there any way to access the field with Javascript to adjust the phone number formatting using Composer? Thanks.

Comment: See http://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/24793/possible-to-add-type-attributes-when-using-freeform-composer/24809#24809

Answer (score 0):

Once created through composer - you will be able to check the field ID and then assign JS to that ID.

Or you could use JS to auto format all phone number fields within a form tag... That is if you want all phone number fields to adhere and not just one like above!